# In X-Men: First Class, who was the mutant who made whirlwinds?

Tags: marvel, x-men, character-identification, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-first-class

In *X-Men: First Class*, one of the members of the Hellfire club is a mutant who makes whirlwinds. I don't think his name (either real or 'codename') is ever mentioned, and I don't recognize him.

Who might this windy fellow be?

Comment: Huh! Silly me, I didn't check the credits, and assumed the guy making the whrilwinds was Whirlwind (a mutant in the comics, but rarely if ever actually tied into the various X-related comics - more of an Avengers foe (originally named the Human Top, fighting Hank Pym as Giant-Man).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Riptide: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riptide_(comics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riptide_%28comics%29)

Even though his real name (Janos Quested) and codename (Riptide) match in the [credits](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270798/fullcredits#cast) and in the [comics](http://comicbookdb.com/character.php?ID=7348), the filmmakers seem to have co-opted an existing character and changed his powers and origin entirely. In the comics, Riptide is characterized by having white hair and his body is engulfed in a tornado, as opposed to the film version who has black hair and creates tornadoes separate from his body. He was never associated with the Hellfire Club (neither was Azazel, while we're at it), but instead he served as a member of Mr. Sinister's [Marauders](http://marvel.wikia.com/Marauders_%28Earth-616%29).

The film did keep one fact intact: he's nothing more than a henchman.